# How to filter by date +constant when using odbc / dbplyr? update issue

Tags: r, dplyr, odbc, teradata, dbplyr

I have a previously running code to query a Teradata server that is no longer running after updating R and the required packages.

The issue seems to be related to how `as.Date("X")` is being translated into SQL.
Using `show_query()`, in the prior versions, it came as CAST("X" AS DATE), now SELECT DATE "X" which throws an error when trying to pull the data.

I know it is related to the update because the code still runs on a VM running older versions and querying the same server.

Below are comparison of the two queries.

Example:

```
   library (dplyr)
   library (DBI)
   library (odbc)
   connection <- dbConnect(odbc(), "Teradata")

   tbl(connection, "Teradata_table") %>% 
   head() %>% 
   select(POSIXct_POSIXt_var) %>% 
   mutate(date_var= as.Date(POSIXct_POSIXt_var)) %>% 
   show_query()
```

before it came as:

```
   <SQL>
   SELECT "POSIXct_POSIXt_var", CAST("POSIXct_POSIXt_var" AS DATE) AS "date_var"
   FROM (
     SELECT TOP 6 *
     FROM "Teradata_table"
   ) "q01"
```

using the same code now results in:

```
   <SQL>
   SELECT TOP 6 "POSIXct_POSIXt_var", DATE "POSIXct_POSIXt_var" AS "date_var"
   FROM "Teradata_table"
```

The problem with the latter is that it throws an error when trying to pull the data with `as.data.frame()` or `as_tibble()`.

```
   tbl(connection, "Teradata_table") %>% 
   head() %>% 
   select(POSIXct_POSIXt_var) %>% 
   mutate(date_var = as.Date(POSIXct_POSIXt_var)) %>% 
   as_tibble()
```

> (-3706)Syntax error: expected something between the word 'POSIXct_POSIXt_var' and the 'AS' keyword.

I need to do a lot of data filtering before pulling the data and I am stuck with this, I wonder if anyone else is aware of this and have a solution. I couldn't find any relevant discussion online.

Versions updated from:

R 4.2 to 4.3
dplyr 1.0.10 to 1.1.2
dbplyr 2.2.1 to 2.3.2
odbc 1.3.3 to 1.3.4
DBI is the same 1.1.3

Comment: Is this really only your first SO post?  This has got to be the best first post I've ever seen.  You dug so deeply and explained it so thoroughly.

Comment: Yes it is, long time lurker though. Thank you for reviewing and kind feedback.

Comment: Not exactly helpful, but the issue is that you cannot alias a date literal.  No clue why, or why the SQL getting generated has changed.

Answer (score 3):

If you would prefer `CAST("X" AS DATE)` then you could write:

```r
tbl(connection, "Teradata_table") %>% 
   head() %>% 
   select(POSIXct_POSIXt_var) %>% 
   mutate(date_var = sql('CAST("POSIXct_POSIXt_var" AS DATE)')) %>% 
   collect()
```

> The problem with the latter is that it throws an error when trying to pull the data with as.data.frame() or as_tibble().

Likely this is just because the query isn't evaluated until you execute one of those commands. Using `collect()` or `compute()` achieves the same (the latter keeps the data in the database).

Comment: This has worked, thank you for the suggestion. Implementing **sql()** into the query will definitely help, big time. However, I feel that the dbplyr update discrepancy should be addressed by the package developers. I left a comment in GitHub as @wibeasley suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You appear comfortable with the sql language.  Does you system allow you to directly submit SQL to [`DBI::dbGetQuery()`](https://dbi.r-dbi.org/reference/dbgetquery)?

```r
sql <- 
  "
    SELECT 
      POSIXct_POSIXt_var
      ,CAST(POSIXct_POSIXt_var AS DATE) AS date_var
    FROM (
      SELECT 
        TOP 6 
        *
        FROM Teradata_table
    ) as q01
  "

cnn <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "Teradata")
ds  <- dbGetQuery(cnn, sql)
DBI::dbDisconnect(cnn)
```

Also, it sounds like your dplyr/dbplyr pipeline is fairly long.  If it gets awkward to write as nested subqueries, using [CTEs](https://learnsql.com/blog/what-is-common-table-expression/) may make the logic easier to express.

Even if you can't express everything in SQL, do as much as you can on the database before bringing it into R for further manipulation.  (I can tell you already know this from your last paragraph --I'm saying this mostly for other readers.)

Two other resources are

- https://r-dbi.github.io/odbc/#querying
- https://solutions.posit.co/connections/db/

Comment: Not that comfortable with SQL. Beside the actual query is much much longer. The primary issue is actually in the post title. I am trying to filter by X > (as.Date(Y) + days). Both X and y are  POSIXct POSIXt. This was totally fine prior to the update. Trying different methods like filter(X > (Y+(days *60*60*24)) which also worked on prior version but now throws an error, different that the one mentioned above.

Comment: I don't have access to teradata, so I can't test alternatives.  A little test example with [memdb_frame](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/memdb_frame.html) is translated correctly.  You might file an [issue with dbplyr](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/issues?q=is%3Aissue+date).  I don't see anything like it yet.  In the meantime, you should be able to copy the older version's output from `show_query()` and paste it into `sql` in the example above.

Comment: If it helps you submit an issue, here's the [exact commit](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/commit/83045c593a69c0d981bad0051cf63be24e923c49#diff-c4f086980e5692d16e3337acd7bfefe3a9315135688133ee4f24ea2944ccba3bL113) where they change how dates are cast.  The [current Teradata docs](https://docs.teradata.com/r/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/3p451k4ev~Sx~dDp_QXM6g) seem indicate the explicit `cast()` function.

Comment: Oh wow, you seem to have found exactly what I was looking for. I will submit with dbplyr. Thank you for looking into it.

Comment: Sometimes it can be helpful to use something like `tbl(connection, sql(sql))` using `sql` as defined above. Then you can use "real" SQL, but still fit your analysis in a dbplyr pipeline.